# How to mirror a PDF (flip PDF horizontally)?

Tags: pdf, preview

I have a very large PDF that is a bunch of pages broken up that will be printed then cut and assembled into a large prop for a costume. The PDF was created in such a way that the images add up to a specific height when printed out and assembled. You can see an image of the PDF with the images broken up on it here:
[image: Screenshot of preview]

I want to make it double sided by flipping the PDF horizontally (mirroring the images), re-printing/assembling, and then affixing to the blank side of the first copy of the prop.

I already have a properly scaled PDF for the first side, so that when printed and assembled, the prop is the proper scale. I no longer have access to the original image used to make it so I can't flip the image and try to make the same PDF over again but mirrored.

**How do I flip my already existing PDF horizontally to achieve my goal?**

Comment: Preview app has exactly this function: *Tools > Flip Horizontal|Vertical*

Comment: It does, but it's not always available.

Comment: @SteveChambers Preview only Flips image files, e.g. JPEG, TIFF. Not PDFs.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the PDF? How many rows and columns? Is there overlap between the pages? What do you mean by "a properly scaled PDF"?

Comment: @benwiggy I have updated my question to be clearer about my intent.

Comment: *Damn* you're right, OK then, never mind  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can do this from Preview > Tools > Flip Horizontal/Vertical… however, & I don't know the ruleset for this, the option is not always available.

If not, you can do it in Preview's Print dialog instead, Layout section.
You can then either Print or re-save as another PDF from the menu bottom left of the dialog.

[image]